# Agrupar dados relacionados a uma coluna

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho o seguinte codigo

```
    SELECT 
t2.conta_nome as operacao, t1.provedor_nome as operadora,
perfil, 
count(*) as total 

FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr_tarifacao a 

INNER JOIN telefonia.provedor t1 ON a.operadora = t1.provedor_id 
INNER JOIN telefonia.conta t2 ON a.accountcode = t2.conta_id 
WHERE calldate >= Date_add(now(), interval -60 second)
GROUP by  operacao,operadora
ORDER by operadora 
LIMIT 50 

;
```

---

Que gera:

Operações | Operadoras

GFK OI    | ALGAR

BANCO BMG | EMBRATEL

IESDE     | EMBRATEL

MONTREAL  |EMBRATEL

RENAULT   |EMBRATEL

BANCO BMG |GVT

MONTREAL  |GVT

---

gostaria de saber como faço para agrupar todos valores realcionados a COLUNA OPERADORAS

Comment: Quer fazer isso no lado do cliente (JavaScript/jQuery) certo? ou é NodeJS? Pode colocar o HTML em questão?

Comment: Pergunta ficou clara mas tentou o group_concat  ?   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: adicionei o resultado como imagem, eu gostaria de agrupar os dados da primeira coluna pela segunda sem repetir, por exemplo EMBRATEL repetiria uma unica vez

Comment: ja tentei o group_concat mas não da certo ele não fica relacionado a 2nda coluna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utilize o GROUP_CONCAT para juntar as informações em uma mesma coluna.
Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(cep.strcep) AS CEP,
   cidade.strnome
FROM Cidade
INNER JOIN cep ON cep.intcidadeid = cidade.intcidadeid
GROUP BY (cidade.strnome)
```

Seu select deve ficar parecido com esse:

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(t2.conta_nome) AS operacao,
   t1.provedor_nome as operadora
FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr_tarifacao a
INNER JOIN telefonia.provedor t1 ON a.operadora = t1.provedor_id
INNER JOIN telefonia.conta t2 ON a.accountcode = t2.conta_id
WHERE calldate >= Date_add(now(), interval -60 second)
GROUP by  operadora
LIMIT 50;
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: é isso mesmo nao estava utilizando o group contac corretamente obrigado!